# Yii No data received in post method only on server

Tags: php, yii

Created an API endpoint I which I am submitted data as the body in postman, but it is always empty on the server whereas it works fine on localhost.

Please look at the request[image]

The same request works on localhost but not online. Here is code on the server side I am using `Yii::$app->request->post()` to dump the data, here is the full code of that endpoint. I had tried `$_POST,$_REQUEST` every request is empty on the server,

```
public function actionSocialcheck()
{
    $data = [];
    $model = new User();
    var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(),'')) {
        $social = User::findBySocialLogin($model->socialLogin);
        if (empty($social)) {
            $data['status'] = self::API_OK;
            $data['check'] = false;
        } else {
            if (Yii::$app->request->post('role_id') != $social->role_id) {
                $data['error'] = \Yii::t('app', "You don't have permission to login as " . User::getRoleOptions($social->role_id));
                return $this->response = $data;
            }
            $data['error'] = \yii::t('app', "Social ID already exists.");
            $data['check'] = true;
            $data['status'] = self::API_OK;

            $data['detail'] =$social;
            $data['access-token'] = $social->access_token;
            // $usercl=new User();
            $loginarr = array(
                'device_name' => Yii::$app->request->post('device_name'),
                'device_token' => Yii::$app->request->post('device_token'),
                'device_type' => Yii::$app->request->post('device_type'),
                 );
            $data['login_detail']=$loginarr;

        }
    } else {
        $data['error'] = "Data not posted.";
    }
    $this->response = $data;
}
```

When I try the same request on the local server it works fine here is the output of that 
[image]

Can you please help me out in this case. Thanks

Comment: this was a whole another issue, it was because of fo HTTP and https request. for online had to request over at https

Answer (score -1):

```
public function actionSocialcheck(){

if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){
$data = [];
$social = User::findBySocialLogin(Yii::$app->request->post('socialLogin'));
if (empty($social)){
    $data['status'] = self::API_OK;
    $data['check'] = false;
}else{
       if (Yii::$app->request->post('role_id') != $social->role_id) {
            $data['error'] = \Yii::t('app', "You don't have permission to login as " . User::getRoleOptions($social->role_id));
            return $this->response = $data;
        }
        $data['error'] = \yii::t('app', "Social ID already exists.");
        $data['check'] = true;
        $data['status'] = self::API_OK;

        $data['detail'] =$social;
        $data['access-token'] = $social->access_token;
        $loginarr = array(
            'device_name' => Yii::$app->request->post('device_name'),
            'device_token' => Yii::$app->request->post('device_token'),
            'device_type' => Yii::$app->request->post('device_type'),
             );
        $data['login_detail']=$loginarr;
    }

}else {
    $data['error'] = "Data not posted.";
}
$this->response = $data;
}
```